# Send Google Mail in C# failed because of 403 Insufficient permissions

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I created a console application which sends an email to an address, it shows like:

```
    private static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose, GmailService.Scope.GmailSend };
    private static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API Quickstart";

    private const string SUBJECT = "Some simple subject";
    private static string[] emails = new string[] { "teodorescumihail2008@live.com" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        var msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        {
            Subject = SUBJECT,
            Body = "Test body",
            From = new MailAddress("teodorescumihail2008@gmail.com")
        };

        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("teodorescumihail2008@live.com"));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        msg.Save(sw);

        var result = service.Users.Messages.Send(new Message
        {
            Raw = Base64UrlEncode(sw.ToString())
        }, "me").Execute();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static string Base64UrlEncode(string input)
    {
        var inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        // Special "url-safe" base64 encode.
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes)
          .Replace('+', '-')
          .Replace('/', '_')
          .Replace("=", "");
    }
```

When execute sending email, I received:

[image]

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receiving Insufficient Permission error from DirectoryService](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953024/receiving-insufficient-permission-error-from-directoryservice)

Comment: i authorized in console and add those scope and still 403

Comment: Is this app of yours going to do ore than just sending email?

Comment: Is my app, I want to send a simple email ... that's it !

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you changed your scope in the code without reauthorize/getting a new credential file from Gmail. The problem is GmailAPI does not know that your scope is updated. You have to reauthorize your app in [GmailAPI](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/gmail.googleapis.com/credentials) by deleting your app permission and regenerate your credentials.json so that your scope is updated on GmailAPI.

To delete your app permission: [click here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions)