# Google Play In-App Purchases - Server side verification

Tags: android, xamarin.android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-console

I implemented server side IAP verification using this guide, except I'm using Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3 instead of v2: http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/securing-google-play-in-app-purchases-for-xamarin-with-azure-functions

Every time I call the "request.ExecuteAsync()" line to make the API access to Google, I get an exception with the following content:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation. [401]
Errors [
    Message[The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.] Location[ - ] Reason[permissionDenied] Domain[androidpublisher]
]
```

There is absolutely no documentation on how to setup the user properly (and I think the setup should be correct anyway?), so what could cause this issue? I even tried to setup the required user as Administrator and still get this error...

Comment: Did you enable the API in the Console?

Comment: Which API exactly? I added a new service account without assigning any group to it (because it is absolute not clear and a total mess which one, if any, is needed). After the user was created I downloaded the Json for Authentication and grant the new user administrator permissions in the Google Play Console.

Comment: I'm just guessing. You can refer to this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953024/receiving-insufficient-permission-error-from-directoryservice

Comment: Without changing anything except updating the nuget package it starts working. So I guess the last version was bugged... Or the permissions on the play console just needed a lot of time to get active...